# swift - how to delete google maps markers from previous session before app is opened again?

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, google-maps-sdk-ios

What I am trying to accomplish:

```
    open app to see a clear google map view
    place a marker on map
    if the app is navigated away from(i.e. pressing the home button or double pressing home button to go to different app)
        clear all markers on map
```

Right now the markers are being stored and saved until i open the app again, but i would like to have them cleared if the app is navigated away from.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //thought this could possibly clear any previous markers before app fully runs again
    self.googleMapView.clear()

    self.locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
    self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()

    if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        locationManager.startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges()
    }

}

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    self.googleMapView = GMSMapView(frame: self.mapViewContainer.frame)
    self.view.addSubview(self.googleMapView)

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based from this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/marker#remove_a_marker), you can remove a marker from the map by setting your `GMSMarker`'s `map` property to `nil`.

Add this condition at the beginning of the method:

```
func setuplocationMarker(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D) {
   if locationMarker != nil {
       locationMarker.map = nil
   }
   ...
}
```

For reference, you may try this [Swift tutorial](http://www.appcoda.com/google-maps-api-tutorial/).

Comment: worked well, took me a while to figure out where to place the method to call. but for me it worked to call it in the didUpdateLocations method